# How do I create a trigger that will update a column if inserted or updated row is not null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table is EmployeeTest
Column EmployeeCode has a Unique Index where it can allow NULL but cannot be duplicate. It is varchar (16)

I want to update the EffectiveDate column

I want to create a trigger for whenever I insert or update a row in the table, if EmployeeCode is NULL, then do not update EffectiveDate.

If a row is created or updated and EmployeeCode is not null, I want the update trigger to set EffectiveDate to GETDATE()

I want it to update EffectiveDate just for the row being edited or inserted.

I cannot get this to work. I keep getting "incorrect syntax near the word 'EmployeeCode'

Can anyone assist me with this?

```
After Update, Insert
AS BEGIN

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF COLUMN EmployeeCode = NULL RETURN;

UPDATE EmployeeTest
Set EffectiveDate = GETDATE()
FROM EmployeeTest D
join inserted i on D.id = i.id

END
```

Comment: Where did you find `if column ...` in the documentation? Assuming that line worked, what would the expected behaviour be if two rows were inserted where one had a NULL value, the other didn't?

Comment: Why so complicated? You already join the inserted table - just filter that join for <not null> values of EmployeeCode. And rather than use @@ROWCOUNT in your first statement, use `if exists (select * from inserted) then return;` I suspect that update logic is flawed but that is something for you to discover in your testing.

Comment: You don't need the `IF` blocks *(they're not only syntactically incorrect, they're not needed)*.  Instead, just write your `UPDATE` to modify no rows in those two cases.  *(The `INNER JOIN` will already deals with 0 rows being in the `inserted` table, you just need a `WHERE` clause to only include the `inserted` rows that you want to act on.)*

Comment: Thank you guys.. SQL newbie here. Instead of breaking my keyboard trying to overcomplicate things, I decided to just ask. Happy I did! Appreciate you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply update only the rows that have a non-null value:

```
update t set EffectiveDate = Getdate()
from inserted i join EmployeeTest t on t.id = i.id
where i.EmployeeCode is not null;
```

And remove the *If column* line.

Comment: This did it. I was trying to overcomplicate things. Thanks!!